# Elementary OS not play audio with other monitor in hdmi

Tags: audio, hdmi

I had Elementary OS installed in my notebook, a Dell n4050, running almost 100%, there was only one failure, when I connected the hdmi cable to an external monitor (Samsung) it does not recognize the monitor audio. I looked for some forums but nothing very productive. Has anyone gone through this? How did you correct the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. I installed pulseadio volume control from the app center.
Just go to the last tab "configuration" and select the right profile.

Comment: yes, I installed the pulseaudio, it solved. Thank you